# ASP.net webform Display information from Database

Tags: asp.net, .net, database, webforms

net web form project where I need to display information from database. I have written code according to research I did online but the webpage still not displaying information from database.
Can some one please take a look at the code and point out error?
Code is below for .aspx and aspx.cs file. Please let me know if you want to see any other file code.

**Code from .aspx**

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
           <asp:Table width="100%" CssClass="display responsive nowrap" runat="server" ID="tblCustomers">
               <asp:TableHeaderRow TableSection="TableHeader">
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>First Name</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>Last Name</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>Date of Birth</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>Age</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>Gender</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>Address 1</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>Address 2</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>City</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>State</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>Zip Code</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>Email</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>How did you hear about us?</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>What you are trying to achieve?</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell>Plan</asp:TableHeaderCell>
               </asp:TableHeaderRow>
           </asp:Table>
        </div>
    </form>
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#tblCustomers').DataTable();

        } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code from .aspx.cs file**

```
using Final_Project.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Final_Project
{
    public partial class View_customers : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SimpleFormContext context = new SimpleFormContext())
            {
                var customers = context.Customers.ToList();
                TableRow row;
                foreach (Customer c in customers)
                {
                    row = new TableRow();
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.Firstname });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.Lastname });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.DOB });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.Age.ToString() });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.Gender });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.Address1 });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.Address2 });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.City });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.State });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.zipcode });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.email });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.hear });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.achieve });
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.plan });

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only `creating` rows and `not adding` to the `table`. Add `rows` to the `table` inside the `loop` to display data.

```
tblCustomers.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: for some reason in this line error shows under (row).

Comment: have you written this inside foreach loop ? After this line `row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = c.plan });`